# How to write conditionals across multiple columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image]

I am trying to write some conditional python statements, where if we have `issue_status` of `10` or `40` AND `market_phase` of `0` AND `tade_state` of    (which is what we have in all of the cases in the above screenshot). Then I want to call a function called `resolve_collision_mp(...)`.

Can I write the conditional in Python as follows?

```
# Collision for issue_status == 10
if market_info_df['issue_status'].eq('10').all() and market_info_df['market_phase'].eq('0').all() \
        and market_info_df['trading_state'] == '  ': # need to change this, can't have equality for dataframe, need loc[...]
    return resolve_collision_mp_10(market_info_df)

# Collision for issue_status == 40
if market_info_df['issue_status'].eq('40').all() and market_info_df['market_phase'].eq('0').all() \
        and not market_info_df['trading_state']:
    return resolve_collision_mp_40(market_info_df)
```

I don't think the above is correct, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what are the details of the **resolve_collision_mp_40** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply()` with the relevant conditions,

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: resolve_collision_mp_10(row) if (row['issue_status'] == 10 and row['market_phase'] == 0 and row['tade_state'] = '') else None, axis=1)

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: resolve_collision_mp_40(row) if (row['issue_status'] == 40 and row['market_phase'] == 0 and row['tade_state'] = '') else None, axis=1)
```

Note: I am assuming that you are trying to create a new column with the return values of the `resolve_collision_mp_10` and `resolve_collision_mp_40` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Minura, am I right in understanding that whatever I put in the `resolve_collision_mp_10` will fill the value in the new column for that particular row?

Comment: After the last comma, it also says `else` is expected?

Comment: @PatrickChong, my apologies. I forgot the `else` statement there. Like any function, `lambda` functions must have a return value.
I have edited my answer by adding the `else` statements. I have just returned `None`, but if you have a default value that you would like to include, by all means, make the change.
As for your first comment, you are absolutely correct. The return values of your functions will fill up this column.